# add +10 in sql field with python

Tags: python, sqlite

```py
import sqlite3

connection =  sqlite3.connect('base.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

a = int(input("ID ?"))


if a == 1 :
    add = cursor.execute('UPDATE users SET user_point = user_point+10 WHERE id = 1')
    req = cursor.execute('SELECT user_name,user_point FROM users WHERE id = 1')
    print (req.fetchall())
    print("Vous avez gagnez 10 points !")
```

So i need to know how to add 10 to my user_point field, if i want to rerun my script and if my id is 1 user_point got 20 per exemple...

Comment: You need to execute both `add` and `req`. Add `add.fetchall()` before `req.fetchall()`.

Comment: hummm i'm sorry i a beginer in pyhton i don't understand where i have to put this ?

Comment: As suggested below Edit your question and put the answer code with the error as your question. Then delete the answer because it is not an answer.